# using sed to replace string in any given line in a file

Tags: bash, ssh, replace, sed

I am trying to replace a string inside of any matching line within a file, for the most part I know how to do this.

What I can't figure out / find info on is how to parse speical chars in the line.

```
sed -i 's/10.10.10.1/10.10.10.48/g' *.db
```

Nothing special with this, I use simular ones all the time. What I am trying to do is this.

Cut `$_CFG["document_root"].` from a line.

IE: So line one below looks like line two below.

```
  include($_CFG["document_root"]."inc/header.inc.dsp.php")
  include("inc/header.inc.dsp.php")
```

Thanks a bunch in advance, I am still looking around while I post this for examples. Its been the better part of an hour so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters e.g. `[`.

```
sed 's/$_CFG\["document_root"\]\.//g' file
```